# Contributing to a core grunt task on github

Tags: javascript, git, node.js, github, gruntjs

I want to create a pull request on github for an alteration I've made to the grunt qunit task but am having trouble getting a local copy of the repo I can work with.

1. The master branch doesn't contain the `tasks` directory so I cloned the v0.3-stable branch instead but I imagine it's master rather than the stable release I will want to try and push to - how do I achieve this.
2. When running `grunt test` within my clone of the 0.3-stable branch lots of node modules are undefined, so I have to install them locally... even though they are all available in my /usr/lib/ ... /node_modules directory. How can I get grunt to use these global copies? (qunit normally runs fine when used as part of a grunt build for e.g. a local directory containing a jquery plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was temporarily difficult to know  where to push too as in the run up to v4 most core grunt tasks were taken out into their own `grunt-contrib-taskname` repos. However, now pushing to those repos is straightforward

Answer (score 0):

1. You can submit a pull request from a branch that isn't master. You can simply use the `v0.3-stable` branch in your fork, and make sure you use that branch instead of `master` in your pull request.
2. You may need to install the node modules in the current directory, even if you already have them installed globally (they may be different versions). Try running `npm install` in the root directory of the repository first.